# what interpolation method can I use for reliefs

Tags: computational-geometry, approximation, computation-models, image-processing

I need to know which interpolation method is the best for working with reliefs, that is, to know the elevations or depths of a given terrain a set of points.

Comment: Questions as short as this usually aren't very good questions. If the question really is as simple you make it look, in which case you should be able to find the answer with only a small amount of research. Otherwise, you're probably missing a whole bunch of context that makes your question too broad to be reasonably answerable. There usually isn't a single best method for anything.

Comment: It's a huge area, and it's called "Digital Terrain Modeling" - good luck with reading!